# RBF Layer - difficulty in understanding

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I wanted to implement an **RBFN** and found this code on StackOverflow itself. While I do understand some of the code, I do not understand what `gamma`, `kwargs`, and the entire `call` function.
Can someone please explain it to me?

```
from keras.layers import Layer
from keras import backend as K

class RBFLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, gamma, **kwargs):
        super(RBFLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units
        self.gamma = K.cast_to_floatx(gamma)
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.mu = self.add_weight(name='mu',
                              shape=(int(input_shape[1]), self.units),
                              initializer='uniform',
                              trainable=True)
    super(RBFLayer, self).build(input_shape)

def call(self, inputs):
    diff = K.expand_dims(inputs) - self.mu
    l2 = K.sum(K.pow(diff,2), axis=1)
    res = K.exp(-1 * self.gamma * l2)
    return res

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], self.units)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Gamma**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html): According to the doc: the `gamma` parameter defines how far the influence of a single training example reaches, with low values meaning ‘far’ and high values meaning ‘close’. The behavior of the model is very sensitive to the `gamma` parameter. When `gamma` is very small, the model is too constrained and cannot capture the complexity or “shape” of the data. It's a hyper-parameter.

**kwargs**: `**kwargs` is used to let the functions take an arbitrary number of keyword arguments. [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1769403/9215780).

**Call**: In the call function, you're calculating the radial basis function kernel, ie. RBF kernel, defined as follows.

[image]
[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel).

The calculation of numerator part:

```
diff = K.expand_dims(inputs) - self.mu
l2 = K.sum(K.pow(diff,2), axis=1)
```

The calculation of denominator part:

```
res = K.exp(-1 * self.gamma * l2)
```

The `self.gamma` can be expressed as follows

[image]

Comment: Hi, what's self.mu?

Comment: what is the problem? Do you mean what's the purpose of [`self`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self)? Or `self.mu` which is simply the training variable, ie. `x'` in the formula.

Comment: Ah okay, I get it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have awarded the bounty to this answer.